# Function pointer as SLOT argument

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I know that it has similar topics but I beginner C++ programmer and cannot understand their because they have few distinctions from my problem.

I define so type

```
typedef void (MainWindow::*MenuListener)(QAction *);
```

To I can pass as argument a method of my class but in function I need to pass it into SLOT. How I can do it?
Below my function:

```
void MainWindow::showMenu(int count, MenuListener listener)
{
    if(0 < count) {
        int flags = ContextMenu::Remove;

        if(1 == count) { flags |= ContextMenu::Edit; }

        ContextMenu menu("ContextMenu", flags, this);
        connect(&menu, SIGNAL(triggered(QAction*)), this, SLOT(listener));
        menu.exec();
    }
}
```

Function `showMenu()` is the method of `MainWindow` class such as function that I try to pass like `listener` argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time to learn 3 years old Qt's [New Signal Slot Syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax):

```
connect(&menu, &MainWindow::triggered, this, listener);
```

These old `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` macros won't accept function pointers, they expect function signatures.

Comment: Oh, thank you for the quick answer! I don't know that I can fix it so easy!